# What are the path components of $\mathbb{R}_l$?

Tags: general-topology, path-connected, sorgenfrey-line

I am trying to solve

> What are the path components of $\mathbb{R}_l$?

We know that $\mathbb{R}_l$ is lower limit topology.

Definition of path component [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Path_Component)

I am thinking that the path components of $\mathbb{R}_l$ are singleton sets.

MY ATTEMPT:

Suppose it is not, let $A$ be a path connected subspace of $\mathbb{R}_l$ with more than one point. Let $a, b \in A$ such that $a<b$. Then the sets $A \cap (-\infty, b)$ and $A \cap [b, +\infty)$ are open in $A$, and clearly $a \in A \cap (-\infty, b)$ and $b \in A \cap [b, +\infty)$, hence nonempty, and also $A = (A \cap (-\infty, b)) \sqcup (A \cap [b, +\infty))$

But I have no idea how to proceed further. Please help me.

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1770696/connected-components-for-bbb-r-mathcal-t-lower-limit and here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172964/is-r-with-j-d-topology-totally-disconnected

Answer (score 0):

You are right: the only connected subsets of $\Bbb R_l$ are the singletons; in other words, $\Bbb R_l$ is totally disconnected.

Take $a,b\in\Bbb R$, with $a<b$, and suppose that there is a connected subset $C$ of $\Bbb R_l$ such that $a,b\in C$. Let $c\in(a,b)$. Then both $[c,\infty)$ and $[a,c)$ are clopen sets. In particular, $[c,\infty)\cap C$ and $[a,c)\cap C$ are non-empty disjoint subsets of $C$ whose union is $C$. This is impossible, since $C$ is connected.

Comment: Sir, thanks for your answer. But I am asking about path components of $\mathbb{R}_l$.

Comment: Since $\Bbb R_l$ has no connected subsets with more than one element, then, in particular, it has no path-connected subsets with more than one element.